# cutting the initial string dynamically in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the below xml tag as shown its value can be ..

```
<fpml:floatingRateIndex>GBP-LIBOR-BBA</fpml:floatingRateIndex>
<fpml:floatingRateIndex>JPY-LIBOR-BBA</fpml:floatingRateIndex>
```

now I have the below xsl tag to extract the value from xml as shownn below..

```
<abc>
    <xsl:value-of select="../fpml:floatingRateIndex" />
    </abc>

the above xsl tag display value as 

GBP-LIBOR-BBA
JPY-LIBOR-BBA
```

now can you please advise lets say if i want that values to be displayed as

```
LIBOR-BBA
```

so I have removed initial whatever comes as above GBP- AND JPY- is removed please advise how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with a substring.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(string(../fpml:floatingRateIndex), '-')"/>
```

This will return everything after the first `-`.